# Angular: condition within ngClass attribute always treated as true

Tags: css, angular, typescript, data-binding, components

I'm trying to set the CSS class within 'EditDialogComponent' below (which is a modal view), depending on an input property called 'showMe' that is set from 'AppComponent':

1. HTML Code:

   ```
   <div [ngClass]="showMe? 'ui active modal': 'ui modal'">
     <i class="close icon"></i>
     <div class="header">
       Edit
     </div>
     <div class="actions">
       <div class="ui black deny button">
         Cancel
       </div>
       <div (click)="clk()" class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
         OK
         <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. TypeScript Code:

   ```
   import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'edit-dialog',
     templateUrl: './edit-dialog.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./edit-dialog.component.css']
   })
   export class EditDialogComponent implements OnInit {

     @Input() subject: string
     @Input() showMe: boolean

     constructor() { }

     clk() {
       window.alert(this.showMe)
     }
     ngOnInit() {
     }

   }
   ```

This is the HTML code used to include 'EditDialogComponent' into 'AppComponent':

```
<edit-dialog showMe="{{show_edit_modal}}" subject='foobar'></edit-dialog>
```

The problem is that whenever I click on the 'OK' button of the modal, I get always the correct boolean value corresponding to `show_edit_modal` variable of  `AppComponent`. Yet after testing, I found that `ngClass` keeps always treating the input value `showMe` as true.

Why `ngClass` is always treating the input property as true?

Comment: Try `[showMe]="show_edit_modal"` instead.

Comment: @Zircon That solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showMe` input is not being properly bound to `show_edit_modal`.
Instead of:

```
<edit-dialog showMe="{{show_edit_modal}}" subject='foobar'></edit-dialog>
```

You should have:

```
<edit-dialog [showMe]="show_edit_modal" subject='foobar'></edit-dialog>
```

This will cause `showMe` to be set (and updated) by the parent's `show_edit_modal`.

Generally speaking, you should never need to use interpolation (`{{ }}`) inside any html tags. There is usually a different, more proper way of expressing what you need with Angular.